# Surface integral of circle

Tags: integration

i want to calculate the surface of this function: $x^2+y^2=9$ ; $z=0$ for $x\ge0, y\ge0, z\ge0$ and this vektor field: $F=(-y, x, z)$.

I have chosen this parameterization: $\phi(r,\theta)=(r*cos\theta, r*sin\theta, 0)$.

Now i can calculate my $d\overrightarrow{o}=\frac{\delta\phi}{\delta r} x \frac{\delta\phi}{\delta\theta}=(0,0,r*cos(\theta)^2+r*sin(\theta)^2$

Definition of the surface integral: $\int_B\! V* \, \mathrm{d}\overrightarrow{o}=\int_0^{2\pi} \! \int_0^3 \! (-r*sin\theta, r*cos\theta,0)*(0,0,r*cos^2\theta + r*sin^2\theta) \, \mathrm{d}r \, \mathrm{d}\theta.=0$

Is this correct?

Best wishes

Answer (score 2):

Write your vectorfield this way:
$$\begin{gathered}
  F =  - ydx + xdy + zdz \hfill \\
  dF =  - dy \wedge dx + dx \wedge dy = 2dx \wedge dy \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$$

This is given region:
$$\begin{gathered}
  {x^2} + {y^2} = 9 \hfill \\
  z = 0 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$

Use polar coordinates:
$$\left. \begin{gathered}
  x = r\cos (\varphi ) \hfill \\
  y = r\sin (\varphi ) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right\}r = 3$$

Transform volume-element:
$$dx \wedge dy = rdr \wedge d\varphi$$

and integrate:

$$\int\limits_A {dF}  = \int\limits_A {2dx \wedge dy}  = 2\int\limits_0^{2\pi } {\int\limits_0^3 {rdrd\varphi } }  = 2 \cdot \frac{9}{2}\int\limits_0^{2\pi } {d\varphi  = 18\pi } $$